# jpa/hibernate: How to store a date in postgresql without time and milliseconds?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I want to store a a data field without milliseconds, but it doesn't work in this way:

```
@Column(name = "birthday", nullable = false)
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy")
private Date birthday;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: This feature, even if supported, would be highly database dependent.  What is your actual SQL database?

Comment: Hi, I use postgres (and docker)

Comment: Judging from your code you only want to store the date not the time, either add `@Temporal(DATE)` to the field, to indicate you only want to store the date. Or stop using the `Date` class and use the new and recommended  java time version. Use `LocalDate` which is only a date.

Comment: Thank you! I used LocalDate now and it works :)